# Coloring a histogram in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following df:

```
df4<- data.frame(structure(list(Percentage.of.change = c(0.8, 0.6, -0.6, -3.1, 
2.7, -1.4, -3.4, -11.3, -3.8, -6.8, 5, 0.6, -2.7, -2.4, -0.9, 
-2.8, -3.5, 1.2, 4.7, -2.5, -4, -2.9, 0, -2.2, -0.9, -4.1, 0, 
-1.9, -5.2, -6.4, -3.9, -2.5, -3.8, -4.5, -1.8, -3.1, -2.7, -9.2, 
-1.9, -5.9, -6.5, -2.3, 0, -3.8, -4.2, -1.5, 1.7, 0, -0.6, -5.3, 
-0.2)), row.names = c(NA, 51L), class = "data.frame"))
```

With the following histogram code:

```
ggplot(df4, aes(x = Percentage.of.change,  fill = ifelse(df4$Percentage.of.change < 0, "#41A2D0", "grey"), color = "black")) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, col="black")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c( "#41A2D0", "grey"), guide = FALSE) +
  #scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-16,6), breaks = seq(-16,6,1))+
  theme_minimal()+
  labs(x = "Change in Percentage of Body Weight (%)",
       y = "Number of Individuals",
       title = "Relative Weight Change",
       subtitle = "Relative weight change for individuals whose goal was to lose weight and completed the program (n=209)")
```

I am hoping to make all records of values that are less than zero blue, and all those that are equal or greater than zero the color grey. For some reason the bar that is at zero is partially both colors, though it should just be grey. I don't think there is an issue with my `ifelse` statement. Am I misunderstanding the bin size argument? Any help would be appreciated.

Subsetting the dataframe to only a few values (including values above, equal, and below zero) removes this issue but as soon as I include the 51st value (df4 in the code) from the master data sheet, the histogram bar at zero turns to a ratio of color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you set the colors before the binning. Doing so your data gets split into two groups and you get a (stacked) histogram for each group. Hence, the values in the "0" bin which are < 0 show up as a blue bar  and the ones >= 0 as a grey one.

Instead you could use `after_stat` to color your histogram after the `stat` and the binning has been applied. However, in that case the "0" bin will still contain values <0 and >0. Perhaps a better approach would be to set `boundary=0` to "split" at the zero line.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  df4,
  aes(
    x = Percentage.of.change
  )
) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = after_stat(x < 0)),
    binwidth = 1, col = "black", boundary = 0
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("grey", "#41A2D0"), guide = "none"
  ) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(
    x = "Change in Percentage of Body Weight (%)",
    y = "Number of Individuals",
    title = "Relative Weight Change",
    subtitle = "Relative weight change for individuals whose goal was to lose weight and completed the program (n=209)"
  )
```

[image]